# Drawing peformance with Win32

Tags: winapi, win32gui

I am getting a very poor peformance drawing with Win32. It takes too much time and needs improving. Please advise.

Here is what I do.

```
HDC dc = GetDC(wnd);
HDC memoryDc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
HBITMAP memoryMapBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, 400, 400);
HGDIOBJ originalBitmap = SelectObject(memoryDc, memoryMapBitmap);
```

Then, I draw in a for-loop as follows.

```
HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
SetDCBrushColor(memoryDc, colorRef);
FillRect(memoryDc, &rect, brush);
```

And finally, I do a cleanup

```
SelectObject(memoryDc, originalBitmap);
DeleteDC(memoryDc);
ReleaseDC(wnd, dc);
```

Drawing takes a lot of time (several seconds). Is there a way to draw faster with Win32?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `EnableFastDrawing(DRAWING_SPEED_ULTRA_FAST)`. But seriously, show us a [mcve] and we can help

Comment: Sounds like you are creating your off-screen drawing DC whenever you your performing a render cycle. That's a costly operation. Only ever create a DC, when the window size changes. And unless you have a Very Good Reason™ to not perform all your rendering from your `WM_PAINT` handler, simply don't.

Comment: No-no, drawing is not done in WM_PAINT. I draw after loading a file, then I put the bitmap into a control Somehow drawing on the memory bitmap is very slow. Microsoft documentation is not of much help to me, unfortunately. I will keep looking...

Comment: It seems it has to do with the color depth of the display. If it is of 16 colors, drawing is very-very slow. If it is 24-bit color, drawing is instant. Why?

Comment: So we are just going to have to guess what the code is?

Comment: In cleanup you must add `DeleteObject(brush)` and `DeleteObject(memoryMapBitmap)` to prevent resource leak, search for "how to monitor resource leak with Task manager"

Comment: Do I need to DeleteObject(brush) if brush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH) really?

Comment: Color depths below 24bpp are costly, because every single pixel's color now needs to be converted while rendering, in your example from 8-8-8 to 5-6-5 (or 5-5-5). This conversion takes place in software.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks! That's what I thought. Do I need to create the memory bitmap with 24bpp, draw on it and then put it to the control? How do I convert the color depth in the end? Is that needed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have solved it. Below is the solution with some comments.

I have a dialog defined in RC-file. There is a control to display a bitmap image in the dialog.

```
CONTROL         "", IDC_MEMORY_MAP, WC_STATIC, SS_BITMAP | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_SUNKEN, 9, 21, 271, 338, WS_EX_LEFT
```

In the run-time I need to create, draw and display a bitmap:

```
HWND map = GetDlgItem(dlg, IDC_MEMORY_MAP);
HBITMAP bitmap = createMemoryMapBitmap(map);
bitmap = (HBITMAP)SendMessage(map, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bitmap);
DeleteObject(bitmap); // (!) this is a very important line, otherwise old bitmap leaks
```

Code that finds out the size of the bitmap to create:

```
HBITMAP createMemoryMapBitmap(HWND map) {
    RECT rect = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    GetClientRect(map, &rect);
    SIZE size = {rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top};

    HDC dc = GetDC(map);
    HBITMAP bitmap = doCreateMemoryMapBitmap(dc, &size);
    ReleaseDC(map, dc);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Finally, we actually create the bitmap and draw on it:

```
HBITMAP doCreateMemoryMapBitmap(HDC dc, LPSIZE bitmapSize) {
    // create 24bpp bitmap in memory in order to draw fast

    BITMAPINFO info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));
    info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.bmiHeader.biWidth = bitmapSize->cx;
    info.bmiHeader.biHeight = bitmapSize->cy;
    info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    void *pixels = NULL;
    HBITMAP memoryBitmap = CreateDIBSection(dc, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pixels, NULL, 0);

    HDC memoryDc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc); // (!) memoryDc is attached to current thread
    HGDIOBJ originalDcBitmap = SelectObject(memoryDc, memoryBitmap);

    // drawing code here

    // perform windows gdi cleanup

    SelectObject(memoryDc, originalDcBitmap); // restore original bitmap in memoryDC (optional step)
    DeleteDC(memoryDc); // this releases memoryBitmap from memoryDC

    return memoryBitmap;
}
```

The idea above is to create a 24bpp bitmap in the memory and draw on it. This way drawing is fast, as @IInspectable pointed out.

If display is in the indexed color mode, e.g. 16 or 256 colors, it seems Windows native control is smart enough to convert the color depth automatically displaying the bitmap.